# Bash - convert units in list

Tags: bash

I have a list of users like below and I would like to convert the units to gigabytes

```
user1@example.com   Mbox size: 7445440 Kb
user2@example.com   Mbox size: 6622275 Kb
user3@example.com   Mbox size: 4657973 Kb
user"n"@example.com     Mbox size: 3657673 Kb
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What precision do you want? "7 GB"? "7.10GB"? "7.45GB"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For calculations I like to use awk embedded in bash scripts.

Save the script below to a file, e.g. togb.sh and make it executable. If you need decimals, just adapt the printf format.

```
#!/bin/bash - 
awk '{ printf("%5.3f\n", $4 / (1024*1024)); }' $1
```

Store your data in a file data.txt and call the script using the commandline:

```
./togb.sh data.txt 
7
6
4
4
```

To display the list in the same format but with changed units, you would use this slightly changed script:

```
#!/bin/bash - 
awk '{ printf("%s %s %s %5.3f GB\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 / (1024*1024)); }' $1
```

The output of this script would be:

```
user1@example.com Mbox size: 7.270 GB
user2@example.com Mbox size: 6.467 GB
user3@example.com Mbox size: 4.548 GB
user"n"@example.com Mbox size: 3.571 GB
```

By the way, awk can do much more than this, it's in fact ideal for processing data stored in text files.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to display the list in the same format but with new units?

Comment: I have added a second version of the script. Adding three format %s placeholders and $1, $2, $3 is all that's needed

Comment: Of course, to convert from kb to Gb, you'd have to divide by 1024 twice.